# don't I need to use session_start() to use session global variables?

Tags: php, session

A novice php learner. I read in a book, and continue to see this at certain forums and tutorials that the statement: session_start() is required to access all global session variables. And yet, multiple solutions offered at stackoverflow suggest using a block of this sort:

```
if(!(_isset($_SESSION['user']))){
   session_start()
}
```

to be able to access the session variables. Based on my understanding, the session variable $_SESSION['user'] could only have been set at a previous php file by starting a session, and is "only" visible to the current page after the session_start() statement is called. Yet it produces the notice:

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start().
```

what am i missing?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: is that your complete code or is there more to it?

Comment: check if you have some include  or require file that have alreade the session start

Comment: This is a general inquiry, although I have some lengthy scripts that result in the scenario. I think I found my answer though.. (see marked answer). Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first block of code should be checking if the session variable is set, rather than the user variable exists in the session:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

However, if you just ensure that you only have a single session_start() per page then you can avoid the "A session had already been started" notice.

Comment: Ahhh! I think this statement was key to my clarification: 'ensure that you have a single session_start() per page'! I do include some files that perform redundant session_start() calls. Strangely though, the notice never came on a different Apache/MySQL/PHP installation, and I was worried something was legitimately buggy..

Answer (score 3):

session_start() is required to read / set any session variables.

Generally, I would think your code should look like this:

```
session_start()
if(!(_isset($_SESSION['user']))){
   // do stuff here
}
```

However, the error message implies that you have already started the session elsewhere in your file.

Answer (score 1):

You might have auto_start turned on somewhere (php.ini, .htaccess, etc)?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scenario where your error would be triggered :

index.php:

```
 <?php session_start(); 
    require_once('some-page.php'); ?>
```

some-page.php:

```
<?php session_start(); // this would make an error when included to index.nl ?>
```

some-page.php should not have session-start in it as index.php already has started the session.

Also note that going to another page or even closing the tab will not reset your session variables ! so if you set `S_SESSION['user'] = 'someuser';` , you close the tab and go to the website again, the session is still there and $_SESSION['user'] would still have someuser as value ! to manualy destroy the session , use `session_destroy();`

Comment: Thanks for the extended info! I think your answer was relevant, plus the knowledge that session variables can persist after even closing a tab is quite revealing... thanks again.